# VBA code to link data input from manually-made Excel form to database

Tags: vba, excel

I made this Excel form that looks like this (just an example) in `Sheet1`:
[image: User will input data here]

And I want to link the data in C5, C6, C7,  or in other columns, to Sheet `Data`, where I have columns like this: 
[image: Excel Database]

What I want is when a user fills the form and clicked submit, the data from the form will be linked to sheet `Data` and make a new row every time a new data from the form is submitted.

This is what I did so far, but this code doesn't work correctly:

```
Sub Submit_Form()

  Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Sheets("Data")

   LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").C5 
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").C6 
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").C7 
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").C8 
End Sub
```

The error message said: `Runtime Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.`

Anybody can help with this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there:

```
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").C5
```

Should change to :

```
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").value
```

For your second Form to clear the contents you can simply do it like this:

```
Sub Clearform()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8,G8,H7").clearcontents

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre44, thanks so much for the solution, it works now! But do you have any solution how to make it so after clicking submit the contents in the form got reset to blanks again? Right now the last data input is still there. Thanks again!

Comment: You mean you want that reclicking the button, clear the content of the cells C5-C6-C7-C8?

Comment: Yes, Peh below gave the answer, but do you have any idea as how to clear the content of cells C5-C8, G8, and H7? Thanks!

Comment: Range("C5").clearcontents would clear the cells content. You could do a second Macro for that?

Comment: Yes, I am making two separate buttons here: "Submit" and "Clear Form". But somehow this code doesnt work:  Option Explicit
 
Public Sub Clear_Form()
   Dim SourceRange As Range
   Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8", "G8")
    
End Sub   Do you have any idea why? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Pierre44 `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8,G8,H7").clearcontents` should do it. And should be faster.

Comment: @Peh I never needed that, Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Peh and pierre , you guys are AWESOME!! Thanks so much for helping me out! I have upvoted both of your answers, so hopefully you guys can gain some points or anything like that :)), have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line using `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Submit_Form()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8")

    ws.Cells(LastRow, "B").Resize(ColumnSize:=SourceRange.Rows.Count).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRange)

    SourceRange.ClearContents 'clear form
End Sub
```

To add more cells that don't need to be transposed you can add them like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Submit_Form()
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Data")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim TransposeRange As Range
    Set TransposeRange = wsSrc.Range("C5:C8")

    wsDest.Cells(LastRow, "B").Resize(ColumnSize:=TransposeRange.Rows.Count).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TransposeRange)
    wsDest.Cells(LastRow, "F").Value = wsSrc.Range("G5")
    wsDest.Cells(LastRow, "G").Value = wsSrc.Range("H7")

    'clear form
    TransposeRange.ClearContents
    wsSrc.Range("G5,H7").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, thanks for your answer, it works well! But unfortunately I have some other cells in different columns rather than C, so how do you modify this code:   Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8"), to Range C5-C8, G5, H7? Thanks again!

Comment: If you need to add more single cells that are not continuous in the first range I would extend it like shown in my edit.